# Is there a way to change/mod/reconfigure/cheat BioShock 1's hacking mini-game, to something less tedious?

Tags: pc, bioshock

I played BioShock 2 before BioShock 1. I got used to the [BioShock 2 hacking mini-game](http://bioshock.wikia.com/wiki/Hacking#BioShock_2), which is much faster to finish and does not stop the game while you're hacking (fight while you hack!), unlike BioShock 1's hacking mini-game, which is tedious to me and stops the game while you hack.

I find BioShock 1's hacking mini-game an exercise in frustration, since I have hacking OCD and have a habit of hacking every hackable item in sight in BioShock 2 - including security bots attacking me, turrets thrown by Big Daddies, etc. (I'm a master hacker in BioShock 2, in that I don't need a gene tonic to make hacking easier or even use plasmids on machines.)*

So, **is there a way to change/mod/reconfigure BioShock 1's hacking mini-game, to something less tedious?**

Note: I'm not looking for tips on how to effectively play the hacking mini-game or to use the auto-hack tool or buyout instead (there's already a [wiki article about that](http://bioshock.wikia.com/wiki/Hacking)). I'm looking to know how to either skip the hacking minigame through, for example: configuration modification, console commands/cheat codes (infinite auto-hack tool), trainers, mods, etc., that will effectively make a machine hacked, every time I try to hack one, skipping the mini-game. That, or make it significantly faster and less tedious to do, or convert it to BioShock 2's  [single player](http://bioshock.wikia.com/wiki/Hacking#BioShock_2) or [multi-player hacking system](http://bioshock.wikia.com/wiki/Hacking#BioShock_2_Multiplayer)<sup>†</sup>.

---

<sup>* Also, there's quicksave/load =)</sup> 
<sup>† "*Hacking appears in BioShock 2's multiplayer experience as a much simpler rendition of the single-player form of hacking. Attempting to hack a machine in multiplayer does not result in a minigame, but instead, a loading bar on screen. Once the bar is full, the hack is complete and the machine is friendly to the player.*"</sup>

Answer (score -3):

Sadly there is no way to speed up the mini game other than i
Imput sensitively and the in game gene enhancements (which really just slow it down)

If cheat is truly an option without just hacking your money use cheat engine to lock your auto hackers so its infinate free hack (personally it's less cheap than hacking the money or adam)

Comment: And can you just install Cheat Engine, open BioShock, and race through the minigames? If not, can you explain *how* that would work?

Comment: You use cheat engine to hack and lock a number value in a game on this case money or auto hack tools

Comment: I get that, but you have to add that to your answer in order for it to actually be a helpful answer. Have you tried hacking BioShock using Cheat Engine? Do you know the numerical values for the parameters you need to edit?

Answer (score -4):

Buying out the machines cost very little and wastes no time. Auto hacks are also useful. However, the safes have a high buyout rate. If you search around awhile you could find a mod, but considering the low buyout rate, as long as you are not low on cash a mod shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: He explicitly stated that he's aware of the buyout and hack tool and doesn't want to use them.